# uploading a file using AJAX

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

myI have been trying to upload a file to the server and I am having difficulties it seems that the file is not being sent to the server.  I found this question [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery) But I cant see much being done differently in that example from what I have.  I have the following form:

```
<form id = "selectFileForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
<input type = 'file' multiple ='multiple'>
</form>
```

then in javascript I have the following:

```
submitForm : function(){
    var uploadFormData = new FormData(document.getElementById("selectFileForm"));

    $.ajax({
        url : "myHandler.ashx/fileUpload",
        type: "POST",
        data : uploadFormData,
        processData : false,
        contentType : false
    });
}
```

In my handler(ASP 2.0) I have the following code:

```
private string fileUpload(HttpContext context)
{   
return context.Request.InputStream.Length.ToString();
}
```

This handler is giving me a response of 44 which seems small the file is definitely bigger than that.  Which makes me believe the the file isn't getting sent in the request.

Comment: you might want to look into this .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963787/file-upload-with-jquery-ajax-and-handler-ashx-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer did help me to resolve my issue... stackoverflow.com/questions/16963787/

Th problem was I needed to add this to my javascript

```
formData.append('file', $('#file')[0].files[0]);
```

This will work for a single file upload but if you are using the multiple option on an input type file, you will need a for loop that appends each file like so :

```
for(var i =0; i < files.length; i++)
{
    uploadFormData.append('file',files[i]);
}
```